# Solving ABIs warning

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on OpenCV with Android. And I tried Face detection sample. But I have a problem.

> "WARNING: ABIs [arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi] set by
>   'android.injected.build.abi' gradle flag contained 'ARMEABI,
>   ARM64_V8A' not targeted by this project."

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this warning, it's just a warning, after all. Or, you can edit your app **build.gradle** script to only work with armeabi-v7a:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually build.grandle already like this. But When I run the app. I see "OCV Face Detection shut down" on phone screen.

Comment: If your APK has some 3rd party arm64-v8a native libraries included, you may face such problem. In this case, use splits to keep single ABI.